# How do I enable @Transactional annotation processing in a Spring (not boot) app?

Tags: java, spring

I have a legacy application that is using Spring with Struts.  I want to make use of the `@Transactional` annotation such that I don't have to do something like

```java
public void transactionalOp(Req request, Resp responseObserver) {

  // Wrap function call in transaction to prevent
  //  "javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException:
  final var transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(platformTransactionManager);
  transactionTemplate.executeWithoutResult(transactionStatus ->
    internalTransactionalOp(request, responseObserver)
  );
}
```

And instead simply do

```java
@Transactional
public void transactionalOp(Req request, Resp responseObserver) {

  // code for internalTransactionalOp(request, responseObserver)

}
```

I have `PlatformTransactionManager` available already.

I'd like `@Transactional` since it avoids a bit of boilerplate

Comment: All the information you need is there: https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring

Answer (score 0):

Basically it takes no more effort than to add a configuration class to enable transaction management by annotating a class with `@Configuration @EnableTransactionManagement`.
That's it, non-private methods annotated with `@Transactional` (the Spring framework one, but you may use `jakarta.transaction.Transactional` as an alternative) will be in transactional scope.

But as mentioned in Spring framework documentation you may take a look closer here to get a grasp of the concepts behind: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/transaction/declarative/tx-decl-explained.html